# Drop array values if they exist in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a list of urls stored in a database, and I want to run a bit of code that checks an array of urls vs what is stored in the database. If the value exists, I want that value from the array dropped.

So far, I have a database that contains 3 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE links
(
     link_id INT(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     url VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
     last_visited TIMESTAMP,
     PRIMARY KEY (link_id),
     UNIQUE KEY (url)
)
```

And basically I'm just trying to insert the data vs a unique value via an INSERT command and if it fails, i'd like to remove that array value. Is this possible?

My bad code:

```
foreach ($urlArray as $url) {

     $sql = "INSERT INTO linkz (url, last_visited) VALUES ('".$url."', NOW())";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
      // remove array here somehow?
    }

}
```

Is there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
Tre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop a value from an array using `unset`. To do this, you need to know the key, so you might consider modifying your `foreach` to include the key:

```
foreach ($urlArray as $key => $url) {
    ...

    // Remove the item from the array
    unset($urlArray[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I was thinking of something along this line, but was unsure about the $key=>$url portion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that's one way to do it.  There are several issues:

- Non-normalized URL notation
- Changing a table to test for existence

The first issue is that there are a large number of ways of expressing any given URL.  For example:  http://www.example.com/somepage can be written http://www.example.com/%73omepage

The other is that philosophically speaking, a pure test for some data in a database should not change the database, whether or not it already exists.  A simple `SELECT * FROM links WHERE url=whatever` is the cleaner approach.  Presumably you have an unstated goal of collecting URLs.

@mfonda has already answered the literal question.